# Push ViewController inside View that was presented with hero animation

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

The title pretty much says it all. I have a `ViewController` which I `present` like this:

```
let communityVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CommunityVC") as! CommunityViewController
communityVC.hero.modalAnimationType = .zoomSlide(direction: .right)
let addButtonHeroID = "addWishButtonID"
self.addButton.heroID = addButtonHeroID
communityVC.homeButton.heroID = addButtonHeroID
self.present(communityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The thing is that insice `comunityVC` I would like to `push` another `ViewController`. Is that somehow possible? I couldnt really find a `Swift` solution that is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to present `communityVC` after embedding the `UINavigationController`, then you can push the view controller inside `communityVC`, so you can push ViewController by using `navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)` from `communityV`

```
    let communityVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CommunityVC") as! CommunityViewController
    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: communityVC) 
    communityVC.hero.modalAnimationType = .zoomSlide(direction: .right)
    let addButtonHeroID = "addWishButtonID"
    self.addButton.heroID = addButtonHeroID
    communityVC.homeButton.heroID = addButtonHeroID
    self.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: 'Thread 1: "Application tried to present modally a view controller <Wishlists.CommunityViewController: 0x11660ed70> that has a parent view controller <UINavigationController: 0x117817e00>."
'

Comment: oh, couldve seen that myself.. Thanks man! Working like a charm

Comment: Hey Piyush, your solution is working fine. But when simply calling `self.navigationController.push(someVC)`  in another `ViewController` pushed it like it is in a `modalView`. How can I *reset* if I want to have the default push animation in another ViewController ?